# Seg fault while using _mm256_i64gather_pd

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I am trying to use the gather intrinsic provided by AVX2 but the code exists with a segmentation fault.

```
double src[100];

// src initialization here
int indices[10] = { 2, 10, 12, 13, 48, 60, 71, 79, 94, 97};
index = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const*>(indices));

elements = _mm256_i64gather_pd(reinterpret_cast<double const*>(src), index, 8); // Segmentation fault happens here
```

I am not sure what is causing the problem. The scale has to be 8 since the type here is double. What am I doing anything wrong? I am compiling with -mavx2 flag.

Comment: With `reinterpret_cast<__m256i const*>(indices)` do you expect to convert each *element* of the array to a `__m256i` value? That's not how it works.

Comment: Regarding that cast, assuming the common 4-byte `int` the array will be `40` bytes, or 320 bits. That's not a multiple of 256 bits. The cast itself will break strict aliasing. And there are different alignment requirements. So that cast is really not a good idea.

Comment: I even used (const __m256i_u*) - that did not fix the issue

Comment: I am able to print the index elements and the elements loaded it to it are right. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: It's not the type of cast that is wrong, it's that you use the data in the wrong way.

Comment: And about casts, there's shouldn't be a need for a cast in `reinterpret_cast<double const*>(src)`. Arrays naturally decay to pointers to their first element, so using plain `src` will give you a pointer of type `double*`. And all pointers can be implicitly converted to their const variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <immintrin.h> // Include the appropriate header for AVX intrinsics

    double src[100];
    // src initialization here

       // Use int64_t for 64-bit integers - cause of the problem
    int64_t indices[10] = { 2, 10, 12, 13, 48, 60, 71, 79, 94, 97 };

    __m256i index = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const*>(indices));
    __m256d elements = _mm256_i64gather_pd(reinterpret_cast<double const*>(src), index, 8);
```

Comment: I have added the header file. Without it the compilation would fail. The problem was with the int type.

Comment: Please read about [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).